# Controlling Dynamixel Ax-12 With Arduino Mega

Tags: arduino-mega

I want to controll two dynamixel ax-12 servos using a arduino mega and I don`t know the commands that I should send to them using Serial.

Could anyone help me with this?
(And please keep in mind that I don`t want any more hardware. Just arduino board)

Comment: I believe that that site might help you;
http://support.robotis.com/en/techsupport_eng.htm#product/dynamixel/ax_series/dxl_ax_actuator.htm

On the left menu, seek that menu path:
Home > Software Help > Software development kit > Controller Embedded C

Comment: how to read position, and the hardware configuration ? pls help me

Answer (score 2):

With [Dynamixel library](http://savageelectronics.blogspot.fi/2011/08/actualizacion-biblioteca-dynamixel.html) you can use servo this easily:

```
#include <DynamixelSerial.h>

void setup(){
   Dynamixel.begin(1000000,2);  // Inicialize the servo at 1Mbps and Pin Control 2
}

void loop(){
    Dynamixel.move(1,0);
    delay(2000);
    Dynamixel.move(1,500);
    delay(2000);
    Dynamixel.move(1,1000);
    delay(2000);
}
```

Example moves servo and makes pauses of 2 sec.

Installation is easy:

> Installation:
>
> Copy the files from DynamixeSerial to your IDE libraries folder.

DynamixelSerial folder can be found here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/dynamixelforarduino/files/?source=navbar

Comment: But how to connect the arduino and servo?The servo requires half-duplex serial port,but arduino is uart.I want to control the servo and also read the data from it.