# Controlling dynamixel servo from Arduino-Mega

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, arduino-mega, servo, robotics

I was trying to control a dynamixel servo from Arduino Mega. The protocol for the communication is half duplex, and I successfully sent data to the servo motor and got it actuated/turned the LED on and off. However, unfortunately, the status packet coming back from the servo is somehow corrupted. I am only getting everything `0xFF`.

The code used is

```
#include <Arduino.h>

#define Direction_PIN PG5

#define TX_DIRECTION (PORTG |= 1<< Direction_PIN)
#define RX_DIRECTION (PORTG &= ~(1<<Direction_PIN))

#define FOSC 16000000
#define BAUD 57600
#define BAUD_UBRR (FOSC / 16/ BAUD - 1)

void USART_initialization();

void USART_Transmit(unsigned char data);

unsigned short update_crc(unsigned short crc_accum, unsigned char *data_blk_ptr, unsigned short data_blk_size);


void sendData_to_Dxl(unsigned char *packet, uint8_t n);

void USART_initialization() {
    /* Set baud rate */
    UBRR2H = (unsigned char) (BAUD_UBRR >> 8);
    UBRR2L = (unsigned char) BAUD_UBRR;
    /* Enable receiver and transmitter */
    UCSR2B = (1 << RXEN2) | (1 << TXEN2) | (1 << RXCIE2) | (1 << TXCIE2);
    /* Set frame format : 8data, 1stop bit; no parity */
    UCSR2C = (3 << UCSZ20);
}

/*
 * DXL Specific Codes
 */
unsigned short update_crc(unsigned short crc_accum,
                          unsigned char *data_blk_ptr,
                          unsigned short data_blk_size) {
    unsigned short i, j;
    unsigned short crc_table[256] = {
            0x0000, 0x8005, 0x800F, 0x000A, 0x801B, 0x001E, 0x0014, 0x8011,
            0x8033, 0x0036, 0x003C, 0x8039, 0x0028, 0x802D, 0x8027, 0x0022,
            0x8063, 0x0066, 0x006C, 0x8069, 0x0078, 0x807D, 0x8077, 0x0072,
            0x0050, 0x8055, 0x805F, 0x005A, 0x804B, 0x004E, 0x0044, 0x8041,
            0x80C3, 0x00C6, 0x00CC, 0x80C9, 0x00D8, 0x80DD, 0x80D7, 0x00D2,
            0x00F0, 0x80F5, 0x80FF, 0x00FA, 0x80EB, 0x00EE, 0x00E4, 0x80E1,
            0x00A0, 0x80A5, 0x80AF, 0x00AA, 0x80BB, 0x00BE, 0x00B4, 0x80B1,
            0x8093, 0x0096, 0x009C, 0x8099, 0x0088, 0x808D, 0x8087, 0x0082,
            0x8183, 0x0186, 0x018C, 0x8189, 0x0198, 0x819D, 0x8197, 0x0192,
            0x01B0, 0x81B5, 0x81BF, 0x01BA, 0x81AB, 0x01AE, 0x01A4, 0x81A1,
            0x01E0, 0x81E5, 0x81EF, 0x01EA, 0x81FB, 0x01FE, 0x01F4, 0x81F1,
            0x81D3, 0x01D6, 0x01DC, 0x81D9, 0x01C8, 0x81CD, 0x81C7, 0x01C2,
            0x0140, 0x8145, 0x814F, 0x014A, 0x815B, 0x015E, 0x0154, 0x8151,
            0x8173, 0x0176, 0x017C, 0x8179, 0x0168, 0x816D, 0x8167, 0x0162,
            0x8123, 0x0126, 0x012C, 0x8129, 0x0138, 0x813D, 0x8137, 0x0132,
            0x0110, 0x8115, 0x811F, 0x011A, 0x810B, 0x010E, 0x0104, 0x8101,
            0x8303, 0x0306, 0x030C, 0x8309, 0x0318, 0x831D, 0x8317, 0x0312,
            0x0330, 0x8335, 0x833F, 0x033A, 0x832B, 0x032E, 0x0324, 0x8321,
            0x0360, 0x8365, 0x836F, 0x036A, 0x837B, 0x037E, 0x0374, 0x8371,
            0x8353, 0x0356, 0x035C, 0x8359, 0x0348, 0x834D, 0x8347, 0x0342,
            0x03C0, 0x83C5, 0x83CF, 0x03CA, 0x83DB, 0x03DE, 0x03D4, 0x83D1,
            0x83F3, 0x03F6, 0x03FC, 0x83F9, 0x03E8, 0x83ED, 0x83E7, 0x03E2,
            0x83A3, 0x03A6, 0x03AC, 0x83A9, 0x03B8, 0x83BD, 0x83B7, 0x03B2,
            0x0390, 0x8395, 0x839F, 0x039A, 0x838B, 0x038E, 0x0384, 0x8381,
            0x0280, 0x8285, 0x828F, 0x028A, 0x829B, 0x029E, 0x0294, 0x8291,
            0x82B3, 0x02B6, 0x02BC, 0x82B9, 0x02A8, 0x82AD, 0x82A7, 0x02A2,
            0x82E3, 0x02E6, 0x02EC, 0x82E9, 0x02F8, 0x82FD, 0x82F7, 0x02F2,
            0x02D0, 0x82D5, 0x82DF, 0x02DA, 0x82CB, 0x02CE, 0x02C4, 0x82C1,
            0x8243, 0x0246, 0x024C, 0x8249, 0x0258, 0x825D, 0x8257, 0x0252,
            0x0270, 0x8275, 0x827F, 0x027A, 0x826B, 0x026E, 0x0264, 0x8261,
            0x0220, 0x8225, 0x822F, 0x022A, 0x823B, 0x023E, 0x0234, 0x8231,
            0x8213, 0x0216, 0x021C, 0x8219, 0x0208, 0x820D, 0x8207, 0x0202
    };

    for (j = 0; j < data_blk_size; j++) {
        i = ((unsigned short) (crc_accum >> 8) ^ data_blk_ptr[j]) & 0xFF;
        crc_accum = (crc_accum << 8) ^ crc_table[i];
    }
    return crc_accum;
}


void setup() {

    DDRG = (1 << Direction_PIN); // setting the pin4:PG5 as output for controlling the direction
    RX_DIRECTION;

    USART_initialization();

    uint8_t CRC_L = 0x00;
    uint8_t CRC_H = 0x00;

    /* LED ON */
    unsigned char TxPacketLed_ON[] = {
            0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFD, 0x00,
            0x01,
            0x06, 0x00,
            0x03,
            0x41, 0x00,
            0x01,
            CRC_L, CRC_H
    };
    /* LED OFF */
    unsigned char TxPacketLed_OFF[] = {
            0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFD, 0x00,
            0x01,
            0x06, 0x00,
            0x03,
            0x41, 0x00,
            0x00,
            CRC_L, CRC_H
    };

    uint8_t n;

    while (true) {

        n = sizeof(TxPacketLed_ON);
        sendData_to_Dxl(TxPacketLed_ON, n);

        delay(1000);
        n = sizeof(TxPacketLed_OFF);
        sendData_to_Dxl(TxPacketLed_OFF, n);

        delay(1000);
    }
}

void sendData_to_Dxl(unsigned char *packet, uint8_t n) {
    uint8_t CRC_L, CRC_H;
    unsigned short CRC;
    CRC = update_crc(0, packet, n - 2);   // 12 = 5 + Packet Length(7)

    CRC_L = (CRC & 0x00FF);               //Little-endian
    CRC_H = (CRC >> 8) & 0x00FF;

    packet[n - 2] = CRC_L;
    packet[n - 1] = CRC_H;

    TX_DIRECTION;
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        USART_Transmit(packet[i]);
    }
}

void loop() {


}

void USART_Transmit(uint8_t data) {
    /*Wait for empty transmit buffer*/
    while (!(UCSR2A & (1 << UDRE2)));
    /*Transfer the data*/
    UDR2 = data;
}

ISR(USART2_TX_vect) {
    RX_DIRECTION;
}
```

The schematic of the circuit made to drive the servo is shown below. Where `PIN4` is the direction pin and TX and RX are the UART transmit and Receive corresponding to the Serial 2
[image]

There is no part in the code for receiving the status data from the servo motor after the instruction set is sent. A logic analyzer was used, and the instruction data is shown as send, but the status data is all `0xff.`

what is the mistake I am doing here.?

The various link I have used

[MOTOR USED](https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/dxl/x/xl430-w250/)

[dynamixel protocol 2.0](https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/dxl/protocol2/)

[74LS126 datasheet](https://www.futurlec.com/74LS/74LS126.shtml)

[74HC06 datasheet](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0559/1970/6265/files/74ls06-ic-datasheet.pdf?v=1634039614)

I have tried the library from this answer [here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/37081/controlling-dynamixel-ax-12-with-arduino-mega), but the status was faulty.